# Swift remove subview from another class

Tags: swift, subview

I have my ViewController 'chatPage' in which I am presenting a UIView using a xib file called 'chatOverlay'.  I have placed a button inside the xib which when pressed I would like to remove the subview from the chatPage ViewController.

I am not sure how to go about this as the button is in a different class to the subview and has no reference to the ViewController I wish to remove the sub view from.

I am aware I could use a notification observer to notify the viewController but is there an alternative way?

How would I go about removing the subview from within the chatOverlay class when the button is tapped?

chatOverlay:

```
import Foundation

class chatOverlay: UIView {
    @IBAction func closeOverlay(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("CLOSE OVERLAY")
    }
}
```

chatPage:

```
class chatPage: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
         view.addSubview(overlayAdd().show(height: view.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y, tag: 101))
    }
}
```

overlayAdd:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class overlayAdd {

   func show(height: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, tag: Int) -> UIView{
         let chatOverlay = xibLoad().chatOverlay()                  
         chatOverlay.frame.size.height = height
         chatOverlay.frame.size.width = width
         chatOverlay.frame.origin.x = x
         chatOverlay.frame.origin.y = y
         chatOverlay.tag = tag

         let view = chatOverlay

         return view
   }

   func remove(tag: Int){ }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would create an `@IBOutlet` and then set the alpha of the view to 0 to hide, or 1 to show.

Comment: Use a delegate from the `UIView` to the `UIViewController`.

Comment: you should use capitalised names for classes -> `OverlayAdd`, `ChatPageController` and `charOverlay`

Comment: you can use `self.removeFromSuper()` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622421-removefromsuperview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`self.removeFromSuperview()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622421-removefromsuperview)

```
// Completely agree with comments, change to ChatOverlay
class chatOverlay: UIView {  
    @IBAction func closeOverlay(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

If you want it to fade away

```
// Again, completely agree with comments, change to ChatOverlay
class chatOverlay: UIView {
    @IBAction func closeOverlay(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (_) in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

I am really curious how you are using a `UIView` inside `chatOverlay` when you appear to only be importing `Foundation`?  Also, cannot figure out why in `overlayAdd` you are importing both `Foundation` and `UIKit`?  `UIKit` itself imports `Foundation`.  The biggest confussion to me is why do you have a class `overlayAdd` at all?  Shouldn't the `show` function be more of a `create` function (you are not showing it till you add it as a subview) and just be a part of `chatOverlay`?  Something like:

```
// Completely agree with comments, change to ChatOverlay 
class chatOverlay: UIView {
    @IBAction func closeOverlay(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (_) in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    static func create(withFrame: frame, tag: Int) -> UIView{
         let chatOverlay = xibLoad().chatOverlay()                  
         chatOverlay.frame = frame
         chatOverlay.tag = tag
         /*
         What in the world are you trying to do here???

         let view = chatOverlay

         return view

         get rid of these two completely useless lines!
         just return chatOverlay like below...
         */
         return chatOverlay
   }
}
```

and then in chatPage:

```
// Completely agree with comments, change to ChatPage
class chatPage: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
         view.addSubview(chatOverlay.create(withFrame: view.frame, tag: 101))
    }
}
```